# Cakephp 3 Redirect when session expires

Tags: authentication, session, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I use the AuthComponent and I want when the session expires and the user press a link or refreshes, to redirect him on the login page.

However for some actions I don't want above redirect, even if user is logged out, as they are used as an API by another application also.

For example, I want to allow the 'view' action for logged-out users, but redirect the 'index' action.

My AppController.php is:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authorize' => [
                'Acl.Actions' => ['actionPath' => 'controllers/']
            ],
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'username',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'loginAction' => [
                'plugin' => false,
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ],
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Pages',
                'action'     => 'index',
                'plugin'     => 'Pages'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'plugin' => false,
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action'     => 'login'
            ],

        ]);
```

If I add below, 'index' is also working if user is logged-out, even though it should be in deny state.

MyController.php

```
 public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\Event $event)
    {
    $this->Auth->allow('view');
```

The only way I managed to do what I want is to add it in the controller action as:

MyController.php

```
public function index()
    {
        
        if (empty($this->auth_user['username'])) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
        }
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What you are describing seems the opposite of what you're showing, eg your code redirects unauthenticated users on allowed actions, which is also the opposite of what allowing actions is supposed to do. Maybe you need to reword your question, and/or elaborate further on what exactly you're trying to achieve, and how it relates to allowing unauthenticated access to certain actions.

Comment: @ndm I tried to reword my question. Basically I want to override the 'allow all' behaviour for some specific actions of specific controllers. I hope it makes some sense now, please let me know.

Comment: That still doesn't make sense to me I'm afraid. Why would you expect a redirect in your `index()` action when you specifically allowed it to be accessed without authentication? eg, why allow it if you don't actually want to allow it?

Comment: @ndm ok, I removed the allow all. So now I want to explicitly allow some actions.

Comment: What "_allow all_"? There is no such thing in the code that you're showing. The code here explicitly allows only the `index()` action, and then in that action is doing a redirect when the user isn't authenticated. I'm sorry, but I still have no idea what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: What I want is stated as clearly as I can in the first 3 paragraphs. There is obviously something wrong with my code, that is why it's not working. Please check updated above.

Comment: Previously it looked to me that you were talking about one and the same action, but if I understand your update correctly, the problem that you're facing is that when you eg allow the `view` action using `$this->Auth->allow('view')`, other actions like `index` suddenly become accessible to unauthenticated users too?

Comment: yes @ndm, exactly.Is there a solution from this, as I don't find something on the documentation?

Comment: This isn't documented as its not intended behavior. Are you sure that there isn't a call somewhere in your code that doesn't pass a value to `allow()`, eg `$this->Auth->allow()`, which would allow all actions? If you pass a value as in `$this->Auth->allow('view')`, this should definitely _not_ cause any other actions to be allowed. Check in your `index()` action what `debug($this->Auth->allowedActions);` shows, if it contains more than just the `view` action, then I'm pretty sure there must be other `allow()` calls somewhere in your code.

Comment: yes, I had an allow() in appController. So I start from that, and try to deny some actions now. Now $this->Auth->deny('view'); works as I expect. But when I try $this->Auth->deny('index'), I get error "AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aros node identified by "Array...." Is something special with the 'index', or I should look at the ACL lists?

Comment: All actions are denied by default, so to speak. `deny()` doesn't add an action to a "deny list", but instead it will remove that action from the "allow list" if it exists, so there should be no difference between not allowing and denying. I would strongly suggest _not_ to use the "allow all and deny some" approach, as accidentally allowing a protected resource is worse than accidentally denying a public resource. I can't really help much with the ACL stuff as I never used it, I always roll my own, maybe if you show the whole context as far as your relevant code and config is concerned.

Comment: thank you @ndm for your suggestions, which are really helpful. I need to do some more research and update my question if needed.